# I want to rename multiple images in a folder with different name every 10 image using php

Tags: php, rename, php-5.3

I have a file contains for example 1000 images, and I have 100 names, I need to rename every 10 images with one name from the 100 names using php, I had done the following code but it seems it doesn't work ::

Here is the code ::

```
<?php
$names = array("mo1","mo2", "mo3","mo4",...);
$directory = '/Users/apple/Desktop/toyor/';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
$flag = 0;
foreach ($names as $value) {
    for ($i=$flag; $i < count($names); $i++) {
        foreach ($scanned_directory as $file_name) {
            if($flag == 9)
                continue;
            else{
                rename($file_name, $value.generate_random_string());
                $flag++;
            }
        }
    }
}
function generate_random_string($length = 10) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString . rand(10, 99);
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the idea behind the part `$i < count($names)`

Answer (score 0):

The code you have will only rename the first 10 files. I would do something like this.

```
   $name = array('mo1', 'mo2',... 
   $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('..', '.'));
   $flag = 0;
   $current_name = 0;
   foreach ($scanned_directory as $file_name) {
        if ($flag == 9) {
            $flag = 0;
            $current_name++;
        }
        rename($file_name, $name[$current_name].generate_random_string());
        $flag++;
    }
```